# Removing all IDs in a dataframe where any one associated column contains a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks somewhat like this

```
ID Company Accepted
1    A         Yes
1    B         Yes
1    C         No
2    B         No
2    C         No
3    A         No
3    C         Yes
3    D         No
3    E         Yes
4    A         No
4    C         No
```

I want to filter the dataframe so any ID that has a "yes" in acceptance is filtered out. so I am left with

```
ID Company Accepted
2     B       No
2     C       No
4     A       No
4     C       No
```

Thus dropping all rows with an ID that has had any accepts. What would be the smartest way to go about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Sets are efficient as they have O(1) lookup complexity.

```
rem = set(df.loc[df['Accepted'] == 'Yes', 'ID'])
df = df[~df['ID'].isin(rem)]

#     ID Company Accepted
# 3    2       B       No
# 4    2       C       No
# 9    4       A       No
# 10   4       C       No
```

Comment: This is close, but still returns IDs where at least one company has returned a "yes" response. I want to filter such that I only get IDs back where no company has returned "yes."

Answer (score 0):

This will do, if your dataframe is called `df`

```
# find the ids that have at least one 'Yes' entry
yes_ids = df.loc[df.Accepted == 'Yes', 'ID']

# Drop all those indices
df.drop(df[df.ID.isin(yes_ids)].index)
```

Returns:

```
    ID Company Accepted
3    2       B       No
4    2       C       No
9    4       A       No
10   4       C       No
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `filter`

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : (x['Accepted']=='No').all())
Out[1017]: 
    ID Company Accepted
3    2       B       No
4    2       C       No
9    4       A       No
10   4       C       No
```